# How to calculate decile function for given percentile

Tags: python, statistics

I have a percentile (float value in range 0-100). What is the most elegant pytonish way to calculate decile (D01-D10)?

I have similar function for quartile:

```py
def quartile(percentile):
    p = 100 - percentile
    if p <= 25:
        return 'Q1'
    elif p <= 50:
        return 'Q2'
    elif p <= 75:
        return 'Q3'
    else:
        return 'Q4'
```

I'd like to avoid writing ten if-else conditions.

Desired output:

```py
>>> decile(95.5)
'D01'

>>> decile(8.3)
'D10'
```

Comment: so you would pass in a value between 0 and 100 to a function, calculate p = 100 - (value), and then return a string that is Q(number), for example 'Q5' ?

Comment: Could you give a solid example? As in, what would you return from the function if you passed in 7? 97? 52?

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: Divide by the size of each *ile (i.e. for quartile, divide by 25; for decile, divide by 10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace your `quartile` function with a simple arithmetical implementation:

```
def quartile(percentile):
    return f"Q{min(100 - percentile, 99) // 25 + 1}"
```

which gives us:

```
>>> quartile(100)
'Q1'
>>> quartile(75)
'Q2'
>>> quartile(76)
'Q1'
>>> quartile(0)
'Q4'
```

A similar `decile` implementation would be:

```
def decile(percentile):
    return f"D{min(100 - percentile, 99) // 10 + 1}"
```

These two functions are similar enough that you could even define them via a higher order function:

```
def ntile(n, symbol):
    return lambda p: f"{symbol}{min(100 - p, 99) // n + 1}"

quartile = ntile(4, "Q")
decile = ntile(10, "D")
vigintile = ntile(20, "V")
# etc
```